# "Whenever we have some interesting invariant of spaces, we try to cook up a space that represents this invariant"

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, classifying-spaces

In his essay [Classifying Spaces Made Easy](https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/calgary/BG.html)
Baez writes:

> We've seen this trick a couple of times lately, and it's actually a
> big theme in homotopy theory: whenever we have some interesting
> invariant of spaces, we try to cook up a space that "represents" this
> invariant. I could say a LOT more about THIS idea, but that would
> propel us into further heights of abstraction, when what I really want
> is to come down to earth a bit

What is it about? (maybe Baez talked about this in later issues of "This Week's Finds"?) Where can I read more about this?

Comment: I just thought about it: I'll be a little disappointed if Baez meant just representable functors.

Comment: But even if Baez was referring simply to the notion of a representable functor, perhaps he was also referring to some related set of important ideas that I would like to know about.

Comment: The paradigm is that there is a classical problem like detecting when two manifolds are homotopy equivalent ([surgery theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surgery_theory)) and then someone (Quinn) takes this and turns it into a space level observation ([surgery spaces](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/quinngeo.pdf)).

Comment: One important result to mention is the Brown representability theorem, which says that any functor on spaces that 'behaves like a cohomology theory' is represented by some $\Omega$-spectrum. Thus instead of studying singular cohomology, one studies the Eilenberg–MacLane spectrum. Instead of studying K-theory, one studies the K-theory spectrum. Etcetera. See for instance §4.E in Hatcher.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn I know about this, but thanks anyway.

Comment: But isn't that just what Baez is trying to get at? That we have many classical invariants that we want to study, and that stable homotopy theory is saying 'study the spectra that represent these instead'?

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Baez sets out this topic about generalized cohomology theories and spectra right in this essay. In this remark, he obviously means some more general and abstract topic related to "any interesting invariant of spaces" (and promises not to talk about it now).